Why is my custom texture not working?
I am making a custom piston with two geometries and one texture for each:  and 
However, applying the second one (extended_deepslate_piston) to either geometry causes the missing texture to appear instead, even though this texture applies properly in blockbench with the same files that are in Minecraft.
The first texture (deepslate_piston) works perfectly fine.
What’s more strange is that swapping the file names causes the reverse to happen. The first texture will show as missing and the second will show properly.
This seems like a misspelling somewhere, but I copy and pasted the file name into my block.json file, and changing which permutation uses which texture yields the same results.
I have tried changing the name to extendedDeepslate_piston and deepslate_piston_two, both of which did nothing. My block.json file is as follows:
{
    "format_version": "1.21.30",
    "minecraft:block": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "redstone:deepslate_piston",
            "states": {
                "redstone:extended": [ false, true ]
            },
            "menu_category": {
                "category": "items"
            },
            "traits": {
                "minecraft:placement_direction": {
                    "enabled_states": ["minecraft:facing_direction"]
                }
            }
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:collision_box": true,
            "minecraft:selection_box": true,
            "minecraft:destructible_by_mining": {
                "seconds_to_destroy": 1
            },
            "minecraft:destructible_by_explosion": {
                "explosion_resistance": 30
            },
            "minecraft:geometry": "geometry.deepslate_piston",
            "minecraft:material_instances": {
                "*": {
                    "texture": "extended_deepslate_piston",
                    "render_method": "alpha_test"
                }
            },
            "minecraft:map_color": "#ffffff"
        },
        "permutations": [
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'north' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 180, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'south' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'east' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 90, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'west' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [0, 270, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'up' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [-90, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('minecraft:facing_direction') == 'down' ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:transformation": {
                        "rotation": [90, 0, 0]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('redstone:extended') == true ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:geometry": { 
                        "identifier": "geometry.extended_deepslate_piston"
                    },
                    "minecraft:material_instances": {
                    "*": {
                        "texture": "extended_deepslate_piston",
                        "render_method": "alpha_test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "condition": "q.block_state('redstone:extended') == false ",
                "components": {
                    "minecraft:geometry": { 
                        "identifier": "geometry.deepslate_piston"
                    },
                    "minecraft:material_instances": {
                    "*": {
                        "texture": "deepslate_piston",
                        "render_method": "alpha_test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


I figured it out. I didn’t have it defined in terrain_texture, which I didn’t realize was even a thing, as I used the block wizard in blockbench for the first geo, but didn’t want a new block for the second, so I just opened the model, edited it, and saved it, which didn’t update terrain_texture.
